# Why does sbt fail with UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES for play-geojson?

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator

I'm writing a play framework app with GeoJSON, and I was planning to use [play-gejson](https://github.com/jroper/play-geojson). When I added the dependency to `build.sbt` as instructed, activator couldn't find it.

Here's what it says I should add:

```
"com.typesafe.play.extras" %% "play-geojson" % "1.0.0"
```

Any ideas what's up with that?

**UPDATE**

I also tried to add the below resolver - to no avail.

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

Here is the error:

```
ecf-db| activator run
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/michael/Documents/Consulting/sayarch/ECF/Conflict-Database/ecf-db/app/ecf-db/project
[info] Set current project to ecf-db (in build file:/Users/michael/Documents/Consulting/sayarch/ECF/Conflict-Database/ecf-db/app/ecf-db/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/michael/Documents/Consulting/sayarch/ECF/Conflict-Database/ecf-db/app/ecf-db/}root...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.plugins#scala-continuations-library_2.11;1.0.1 .[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play.extras#play-geojson_2.11;1.0.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play.extras#play-geojson_2.11;1.0.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/michael/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play.extras/play-geojson_2.11/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   file:/usr/local/Cellar/typesafe-activator/1.2.12/libexec/repository/com.typesafe.play.extras/play-geojson_2.11/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/extras/play-geojson_2.11/1.0.0/play-geojson_2.11-1.0.0.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/extras/play-geojson_2.11/1.0.0/play-geojson_2.11-1.0.0.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play.extras/play-geojson_2.11/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/extras/play-geojson_2.11/1.0.0/play-geojson_2.11-1.0.0.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/extras/play-geojson_2.11/1.0.0/play-geojson_2.11-1.0.0.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play.extras#play-geojson_2.11;1.0.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play.extras#play-geojson_2.11;1.0.0: not found
```

Build file:

```
name := """XXXXXXXX"""

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

organization := "XXXXXXXXXX"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws,
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0-2",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.1.1-2",
  "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "2.1.3",
  "org.webjars" % "font-awesome" % "4.2.0",
  "com.typesafe.play.extras" %% "play-geojson" % "1.0.0"
)

LessKeys.compress in Assets := true

includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though the `README` hasn't been updated since the latest release. 1.0.0 was built for only Scala 2.10 and not 2.11. But 1.1.0 has been cross-built for Scala 2.10 and 2.11. Just bump the version to 1.1.0:

```
"com.typesafe.play.extras" %% "play-geojson" % "1.1.0"
```

(Or maybe use Scala 2.10 if you need 1.0.0 for some reason)

Comment: Also - adding the resolver is not needed once the version has been bumped.